# Update Database From Grid View Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I have a grid view on a webform that has a hidden field holding the id, how do I capture the data from the id field to use in my update statement?  This is what my syntax looks like...
**HTML**

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="weekofyear" HeaderText="Week" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="supportname" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="supid" HeaderText="SupportIDName" Visible="false"/>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="TicketCompleted" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="TicketCompletedCompleted_Click" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("TicketCompleted")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**C#**

```
protected void TicketCompleted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgRD.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Below captures the checkbox value (yes or no)
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("TicketCompleted");                    
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            //Here is where I will run the update
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change hidden field to a ItemTemplate and add label and bind your id to label; in code behind find that label and get value

Comment: @techspider.  I follow you until finding the value from the ItemTemplate and using C# to get the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="weekofyear" HeaderText="Week" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="supportname" HeaderText="Name"  />
<%--<asp:BoundField DataField="supid" HeaderText="SupportIDName" Visible="false"/>--%>
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("supid") %>' ID="supid" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="TicketCompleted" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="TicketCompletedCompleted_Click" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("TicketCompleted")) %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("TicketCompleted");
if (chk.Checked)
{
    string ID = ((Label)row.FindControl("supid")).Text;
}
```